# PAYPAL ERROR 400 NODEJS

Tags: nodejs, paypal

Segui la documentacion de Paypal sobre como hacer una orden, este es el objeto:

```
var payReq= JSON.stringify({

        "0intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/process",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel",
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": [{
                    "name": "tacos",
                    "sku": "001",
                    "price": "1.00",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": 1
                }]
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "1.00"
            },
            "description": "This is the payment description."
        }]
    });
```

Y esta es la funcion para hacer la orden:

```
paypal.payment.create(payReq, function(error, payment){
        var links = {};

        if(error){
          console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
        } else {
          // Capture HATEOAS links
          payment.links.forEach(function(linkObj){
            links[linkObj.rel] = {
              href: linkObj.href,
              method: linkObj.method
            };
          })

          // If the redirect URL is present, redirect the customer to that URL
          if (links.hasOwnProperty('approval_url')){
            // Redirect the customer to links['approval_url'].href
          } else {
            console.error('no redirect URI present');
          }
        }
      });
```

Y esto es lo que recibo al ejecutar la funcion:

```
{"response":{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"ee13a7fe92652","httpStatusCode":400},"httpStatusCode":400}
```

Segun la documentacion de Paypal el error 400 significa:
Bad Request:
The server could not understand the request, probably due to a syntax error.

Comment: Ya quite el 0 en intent y ahora no recibo nada

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        $payment->create($apiContext);
    } catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        var_dump(json_decode($ex->getData()));
        exit(1);
    }
```

mas quita ese 0intent puede ser por eso

Cuando recibí el error (PHP SDK), detecté la excepción y $ ex-> getData () devolvió un json que contiene los detalles sobre la solicitud incorrecta, en mi caso El código de moneda que di fue incorrecto. Se produjo un error de sintaxis.

Comment: Ahora me sale esto:201

Created

A resource has been created on the server, presumably in response to a client request. The response body should include the URL(s) where the new resource can be found, with the most specific URL set in the Location header. If the resource cannot be created immediately, an SC_ACCEPTED status code should be returned instead.

Comment: 200-299 Client request successful lo cual se supone que ya estas llegando a la respuesta del servidor ya no te da error  Se ha creado un recurso en el servidor, probablemente en respuesta a una solicitud del cliente. El cuerpo de la respuesta debe incluir las URL donde se puede encontrar el nuevo recurso, con la URL más específica establecida en el encabezado de la ubicación. Si el recurso no se puede crear inmediatamente, se debe devolver un código de estado SC_ACCEPTED en su lugar.